# What's the best recommender system for only first-visit recommendations?

Tags: machine-learning, recommender-system

I'm trying to build a recommender system that recommends items to users. However, users come only once and need to be accurately recommended on their first and unique visit, thus making cold start the core of my problem.
I tried many approaches :

- my first idea, and the one that seems to me the most consistent, is to build by hand a matrix features * items (thinking of features and rating 1 to 5 by hand items according to those features), then user gives an input vector (with his preferences) and I simply compute the dot product with my matrix.
- then I tried to build a users * items rating matrix and when a new user comes in, I make him rate some items to fill some blanks and then I compute a matrix factorization the fill all the new row. But this solution is bad for my user experience.

Both methods don't give me good results, specifically and surprisingly the first one whereas I'm giving lot of information and limiting algorithm hazardous guessing (maybe because my rating system is bad, not normalized, need to be regularized, ...)
Do you have any idea ?